# Match and group object properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

i had an object like this i tried to group the object based on the last value of the property but couldn't acheive the desired result. I tried by fetching all the properties and match it using the index value using regex but that didn't worked.

```
{
q_A.1 : "info",
q_B.1 : "info2",
q_C.1 : "info3",
q_D.1 : "info4",
q_A.2 : "information",
q_B.2 : "information2",
q_C.2 : "information3",
q_D.2 : "information4",
}
```

i need to group the object like this

```
[{
q_A.1 : "info",
q_B.1 : "info2",
q_C.1 : "info3",
q_D.1 : "info4",
},
{
q_A.2 : "information",
q_B.2 : "information2",
q_C.2 : "information3",
q_D.2 : "information4",
}]
```

Comment: You said you tried something. Mind to share *what* you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` method to group the objects.

```js
const data = { "q_A.1": "info", "q_B.1": "info2", "q_C.1": "info3", "q_D.1": "info4", "q_A.2": "information", "q_B.2": "information2", "q_C.2": "information3", "q_D.2": "information4" };

const result = Object.values(
  Object.entries(data).reduce(
    (acc, [k, v]) => (Object.assign((acc[k.split(".")[1]] ??= {}), { [k]: v }), acc),
    {}
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

**Relevant Documentations:**

1. [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
2. [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
3. [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
4. [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
5. [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)